# What is the primary key of the method Events: list in google-calendar-api?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to get the calendar data every day that was created or updated at yesterday.

I get events on the specified calendar with google-calendar-api at [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?authuser=1).

For example,today,I want to get the events of calendar data was created or updated at yesterday.

If I can find the primary key of this method, then I update the data with the primary key to the database. If can't find the primary key in database with primary key in response, represents new data is exists,so I insert the new data into the database. If the `status` of the data is `cancelled`, then I delete the data from the database.

Now I have the administrator's account. I can get the gmail account of all employees in my company, and I have added these accounts to my calendar.I can get employees'calendarId, but I want to know which fields I should use as the primary key to do this, use `calendarId` and `iCalUID` to get different data or only use `iCalUID` to get different data?

What is the primary key of the method Events:list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the response data,in fact,the id in items is the primary key(no repetition).

The recurrent events has the same icalUIDs.So we should use id as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
oService.Events.List("This is calenderId,might is your told employee's gmail account")
```

`iCalUID`is an ID from calendar event. Different event have different `iCalUID`

Comment: I don't think so.
Note that the icalUID and the id are not identical and only one of them should be supplied at event creation time. One difference in their semantics is that in recurring events, all occurrences of one event have different ids while they all share the same icalUIDs.You can find it here:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events?authuser=1#resource